# show and hide not working with click function

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.dlop1').hide('fast');    
   $('.dlop2').hide('fast'); 

   $('#dev1').click(function(){ 
     $('.dlop1').show('slow')
   }); 

   $('#dev2').click(function(){ 
    $('.dlop2').show('slow')
   });  
});
```

The given j query code hides dlop1 & dlop2. But do not show them on click. Please help.
the link at js fiddle with similar problem http://jsfiddle.net/4kLor0q4/

Comment: Can you post an example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net, or at least add your HTML to the question. There is no obvious reason this would not work.

Comment: This code works for me. I'm assuming this is a simified version of your code? It may be something else conflicting with it. Also, try putting the click event listeners outside of the ready event listener.

Comment: use `toggle` to show and hide instead of `show`

Comment: .click is deprecated i suggest you to use $().on("click", function(){})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `toggle` to show and hide instead of `show`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.dlop1').hide('fast');    
   $('.dlop2').hide('fast'); 

   $('#dev1').click(function(){ 
     $('.dlop1').toggle('slow');
   }); 

   $('#dev2').click(function(){ 
    $('.dlop2').toggle('slow');
   });  
});
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/v873bk83/

Comment: thank you. but it worked with .show() as well. See:http://jsfiddle.net/v873bk83/2/

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alboy51/2q64s6qb/)

Given your information, everything works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dlop1">dlop1</div>
<div class="dlop2">dlop2</div>
<div id="dev1">dev1</div>
<div id="dev2">dev2</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.dlop1').hide('fast');    
   $('.dlop2').hide('fast'); 

   $('#dev1').click(function(){ 
     $('.dlop1').show('slow')
   }); 

   $('#dev2').click(function(){ 
    $('.dlop2').show('slow')
   });  
});
```

Comment: No I had .dlop1 and .dlop2 inside #dev1 and #dev2 consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons (;) in these lines:

```
$('.dlop1').show('slow')

$('.dlop2').show('slow')
```

Comment: Semicolons are not a necessity in JS, they are not required :)

Comment: wow, didn't actually know that! Have always used semicolons :)

Comment: Well, if you do line separates, then yes. If you write all in the same line, it will not work. Also, I belive you won;t be able to minify it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yup! Altho in Strict mode (a JS mode where less slack is allowed) I do think you'd have to put in semicolons but that's not the case here.

Comment: @Alexey - You are 100% correct. Not using semicolons does have downsides, for compression and consistency purposes I would recommend adding semicolons :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code really.
It all looks good which means you're going to have to debugg.

You can debug code by putting `console.log()`'s in the code to be executed on click.

Your code would look something like this:

```
$('#dev1').click(function() {
    console.log($(this)); //reference to #dev1 but this could be a string as well
    $('.dlop1').show('slow');
});
```

You might also want to check your console for errors when executing the code and double check if elements with the ID of `#dev1` exist or haven't been misspelled - this happens sometimes.

Furthermore, (famous line inc:) as of later jQuery versions (depending on which one you use e.g. 1.7+) `$.on()` is the preferred method for binding events to elements.

documentation for the `$.on()` method can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Hope this helps,
Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" class="name" style="display:none;">Name...</input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="comment();">



<script>


         function comment()
         {

         $('.name').toggle( 3000 );

         }

 </script>


</body>

</html>
```